# Move jQuery-UI tabs to another set

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having 2 sets (set1,set2) of tabs (all created using the add method). I also have both sets to sortable and using the connected-list option of sortable, I've made it possible to move tabs from set1 to set2 and vice versa.

But this doesn't move the div containing the content of the tab. So, I wrote the following function to move the div also (called when the `over` event of sortable is triggered

```
    migrateTabDiv:function(e,ui){
        console.log( ui.item.find("a").attr("href") );
        console.log( $(this).parent() );
        var relatedContentDiv=$( ui.item.find("a").attr("href") );

        console.log(relatedContentDiv);
        $(this).parent().append( relatedContentDiv[0] );
    }
```

This code moves the Div to the correct set but now when I try to make a tab active,I get the following error

`Uncaught jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.`

What I understand from this is that the UI tabs use some kind of internal representation  too which relates a tab content to a set.

The basic functionality that I'm trying to achieve is to be able to drag a tab from one set of tabs into another set of tabs.
How can I make this possible?

Comment: maybe you have to call some kind of function to reinitialize the tabs

Comment: I looked through the tabs page but it doesn't seem to say anything about it.

Comment: hm maybe destroying it an recreating it. but that would probabliy create some flickering

Answer (score 0):

I've hacked together a work around. It is not the most efficient method but it works

```
migrateTabDiv:function(e,ui){

    var oldIndex=ui.item.data('originIndex');
    var label=ui.item.find("a").text();
    var id=ui.item.find("a").attr("href");
    var currentIndex = ui.item.index()+1;


    var jRelatedTabContentDiv=$( id ).find(".tabContent").detach(); //detach and keep the old content

    ui.sender.parent().find( id ).remove(); // remove the old div 
    ui.item.remove(); // remove the tab li that is appended by the sortable in the new set


    $(this).parent().sortable( "refresh" ).tabs("add", id , label, currentIndex);  //add a similar tab
    $(this).parent().find( id ).append( jRelatedTabContentDiv );  //add teh old content
}
```

And the tabs initialisation goes as

```
$("#fileTabsMain").tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
         connectWith: "#fileTabsVSplit .ui-tabs-nav",
         placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
         forcePlaceholderSize:true,
         receive:interfaceView.migrateTabDiv,
         start: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.item.data('originIndex', ui.item.index());
                 },
         });
```

And a similar initialization for #fileTabsVSplit also.

Comment: It seems there are some bugs in this that causes some tabs to be lost while transferring at some point, although I haven't been able to figure out where.

Comment: were u able to find a better solution, thats more robust?

Comment: Not yet, although I haven't touched that part of the code for a while. Working on some other aspects of the system.